# Proving that a function is linear or constant

Tags: calculus, functions, derivatives, logarithms

While doing an analysis for a video game I play, I came up with the following function:

$$f(x)= \frac 1 {\ln(1.01+x/100)-\ln(1+x/100)}$$

which I wanted to simplify. I plugged it into the standard symbolic algebra packages, and they couldn't do anything with it. The derivative doesn't suggest anything either. So, I graphed it, and found it to be indistinguishable from

$$f(x)= 100+\ln(1.01)+x$$

(at least for $x>-1/\ln(1.01)$) as can be seen by evaluating it at any chosen point. ($x=0$ and $x=100$ are easiest). I wanted to prove this, but didn't know where to start.

I tried taking the derivative, hoping I could prove that it is everywhere $1$. But it's even more complicated, and I can't figure out how to simplify it.

This isn't homework, but I don't need a whole solution, just what method I should use to attack it.

Comment: I suggest that you start by using algebra and the properties of logarithms to  simplify the denominator in your expression for $f(x)$.

Comment: This function is rather close to the line $y = x+100$ for values of $x$ that are not too big. And the derivative is rather close to $1$ for values of $x$ that are not too big.

Comment: The approximation should be the reciprocal of what's in the OP.

Comment: Thanks @Χpẘ! Fixed it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can simplify it to $$\large{\frac{1}{\ln(1 + \frac{1}{x+100})}}$$ This is not a linear function.

Comment: Yes, now I see how I was deceived.

Answer (score 1):

Let $f(x) = {1 \over \log({101 \over 100}+{x \over 100}) - \log(1+{x \over 100})}-{1 \over x+\log {101 \over 100}}$.

Compute $f'(0) = {10101 \over 10100 (\log {101 \over 100})^2}$.

(In fact, a little work shows that $f(1) \neq 0$.)

Answer (score 1):

$\ln(1.01+x/100)-\ln(1+x/100)=\ln\frac{1.01+\frac{x}{100}}{1+\frac{x}{100}}=\ln\frac{101+x}{100+x}=\ln(1+\frac1{100+x})\approx \frac1{100+x}$ with the approximation better as $x$ increases. If $x=0$ the approximation is off by about $.00005$. This matches well with the reciprocal of the approximation in the OP, because $\ln 1.01$ is small compared to $100$.

In terms of "proving" the approximation it is well known that $\ln(1+ y) \approx y$ when $y \approx 0$. So you could rely on that. But if you want a more rigorous proof you could resort to the [Taylor series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series#Natural_logarithm) for $\ln(1+y)$. Using that you can formulate the order of the error. For example the approximate error mentioned above, matches the second term of the expansion, namely $.00005 = \frac{.01^2}5$. Alternatively you could derive a better approximation by including more terms from the expansion ($-\frac{x^2}2$, $\ -\frac{x^2}2+\frac{x^3}3$, $\ -\frac{x^2}2+\frac{x^3}3-\frac{x^4}4$, etc.).  Because in your case $y \leq .01$, each successive terms gives about 2 decimal digits more accuracy.